# how create test template instance and execute from RMA FICO Blaze Advisor?

Tags: java, blaze-advisor

I am newbie to the `FICO community Blaze Advisor IDE 7.2 version`. I am looking to developed the `BrUnit` test cases which I developed, now I am looking to create an instance of test cases so that it can be executed from the `Rule Maintenance Application (RMA)`.

Please share steps to create test template instance and how to execute it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to create a Group Template with a 'static' function (Section 'SRL Content'):

[image]

This function must have the Property 'Test Role' set to 'Test':

[image]

Its body can have the Place Holders you need to write your assertions:

[image]

Then you just to use this SingleBrUnit_GroupTemplate as the Type of the Value Holder of another Group Template, that we can call MultipleBrUnits_GroupTemplate:

[image]

An instance of will generate multiple functions that are BrUnits as it is possible ot see then on the BrUnit Runner View of Eclipse on the left side of the Code Editor:

[image]

The generated functions will have the Test Role property set as expected:

[image]

Without this composition of a Group Template (with a 'static' brUnit in it) used as the type of a Value Holder the traditional way to generate functions from Group Templates do not generate them with the Test Role set.